# Using the generic type 'Mapper<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Mapper<T> {

  public static Mapper<T> GetFor<TKey>(T type) {
    return new Mapper<T>();
  }

  public static Mapper<T> GetFor<TKey>(IEnumerable<T> types) {
    return new Mapper<T>();
  }  

  public Mapper<T> Add<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> expression, String name) {

    _fields.Add(name, expression);
    return this;

  }

}
```

I am using a static method as sometimes I need to create a Mapper instance having an anonymous type so I use:

```
var a = new { /* ... */ }
var b = Mapper.GetFor(a);
```

But I get the error:

```
Using the generic type 'Mapper<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

I also tried the following:

```
public class MapperFactory {
  public static Mapper<T> CreateMapperFor<T>(IEnumerable<T> typeProvider) {
    return new Mapper<T>();
  }
}

var a = new { /* ... */ }
var b = MapperFactory.CreateMapperFor(a);
```

Using the factory class works fine ...

1. How to solve the problem with the first version?
2. Should I have a method inside Mapper or use a factory?

I am doing this simply because I have situations where the type is anonymous.

Comment: Why do you need `TKey` in the first example?

Comment: @YacoubMassad just added the Add method which was missing and that is why I am using TKey.

Comment: You still don't need `TKey` in the `GetFor` methods.

Comment: And the parameter `type` does not seem to be used inside the function. (or `types`)

Comment: @DavidG Could you please add some code? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Magnus not sure what you mean

Comment: You are sending in parameter  `T type` and then not use it.

Comment: They mean you don't do `return new Mapper<type>();`, so what's the point in `type`? And `T` is not `TKey`.

Comment: 1) The usual convention for `Add` methods seems to be `Add(key, element)`, as evidenced by the method you call, but you've flipped it for some reason.  2) There doesn't appear to be anything specifying what `TKey` should be, and nothing linking it from the static call to the instance call anyways.  Are you sure you didn't mean something like `Mapper<TKey> GetFor<TKey>(TKey t)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such class as a `Mapper`, only a `Mapper<T>`, so you can't call static methods on such a non-existent class (i.e. `Mapper.GetFor` doesn't resolve).

You need to create a non-generic helper class for this:

```
public class Mapper
{
    public static Mapper<T> GetFor<T>(T templateObject)
    {
        return new Mapper<T>();
    }
}
```

so now you can:

```
var x = new{a = 1, b = 2};
var mapper = Mapper.GetFor(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

> How to solve the problem with the first version?

You don't. To call a static method in a generic class, you need to specify the generic type parameter.

> Should I have a method inside Mapper or use a factory?

Use a non-generic factory class. If you want, you can simply call your factory class `Mapper`. That's what the .NET framework does:

- `Tuple<T1, T2>` is a generic class.
- `Tuple` is the factory class containing the [static factory method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181(v=vs.110).aspx) `Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)`.

Comment: @MiguelMoura: Which part? Your factory class is fine! Just replace `MapperFactory` in your last code example with `Mapper`, if you want to follow the pattern used by Tuple. However, there's nothing wrong with calling it `MapperFactory` either: It's more explicit, and it's what you'd usually do in Java code.

Comment: Was about to say the same but without the very nice Tuple example.

Answer (score 0):

@Heinzi is right, you aren't able to do it this way, it is better to use factory method declared in non-generic class. If you really want to use `Mapper` as `TypeName` (although I don't consider it as a good practice) you could define `static class Mapper` and declare the method there

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static Mapper<T> GetFor<T>(T type)
    {
        return new Mapper<T>();
    }
}
```